# How to update a field in the database upon user session expiration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm allowing the session to expire in session.php after 120 minutes of inactivity. Is there a way to trigger an update in the DB upon session expiration?

I'm trying the below code, and only the first part works where the user is logged in  :

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (\Auth::check()) {
        // The user is logged in...
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $user->lastActive = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user->online = 1;
        $user->save();
        }
        elseif (\Auth::logout()) {

        $user->lastActive = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user->online = 0;
        $user->save();

        }
```

Comment: If you use the database session driver you can attach a SQL trigger to the session table.

Comment: First, how are you determining 120 mins of inactivity? A minutely simple cronjob could also potentially do the trick.

Comment: 'lifetime' => 120,

Comment: So you're not currently tracking your users last activity time?

Comment: Are you talking about when the user actually specifically logs off? Or are you trying to catch when a user times out after the 120 minutes of inactivity

Comment: Laravel has some built in events to handle these types of things, one of them is a [logout](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Logout.html) event. [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#event-subscribers)

Comment: When user times out after 120 minutes.

Comment: The problem there is that NOTHING has happened for 120 minutes. Because nothing has happened there is no way of finding out that nothing has happened because nothing has happened.

Comment: Your only option is to look at the session table at the `last_activity_time` or whatever its called on your system and run a CRON job to register people as logged off after the last activity time is greater than 120 of whatever time you are using